# Popup on if statement in php

Tags: php

I have a html form which looks like this:

```
<form action="submitOrder.php" method="get">
    <select name="orderForm">

    <?php 
        echo '<option value=" "> </option>';

        while($row = \mssql_fetch_array($employeeOrderResult))
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row[EMPLOYEE].'">'.$row[EMPLOYEE].'</option>';
        }
    ?>

    <option value="Gæst">Gæst</option>
    <option value="Praktikant-01">Praktikant-01</option>
    <option value="Praktikant-02">Praktikant-02</option>
    <option value="Praktikant-03">Praktikant-03</option>

    </select>
    <br>
    Vare: <input type ="text" name="varenr"><br>
    Antal: <input type="text" name="antal"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Bestil">
</form>
```

It fetches som data from a database and adds some special guests.
Now, when it confirms it redirects to a page which has this code in it:

```
<?php
    $ofAntal = $_GET['antal'];
    $ofMedarbejder = $_GET['orderForm'];
    $ofDato = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ofVareNr = $_GET['varenr'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Bestillinger(bestillingsAntal,medarbejder,dato,vareNr) VALUES('$ofAntal','$ofMedarbejder','$ofDato','$ofVareNr')";
    $validation = mysql_query($sql, $MySQLcon);

    if(!$validation)
    {
        die('Couldnt enter data ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo 'Entered data succesfully';
?>
```

Now, I need a confirmation popup of some kind, if the amount (ofAntal) is above 1, and Ive looked into several solutions. The problem is i started working with PHP tuesday morning, and i cant find a solution that works for me.
All it has to do, is submit the data is yes is clicked, and cancel it if the user clicks no/cancel. This is ofc done in an IF statement, thats not the issue, the issue is how to implement it properly.

ANY help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this, It can either be a fancy bog like a modal (Google Twitter bootstrap - Modal), or just a simple js/jQuery confirm dialog, (Google js/jQuery confirm box and `event.preventDefault()`  Or, again a simple popup from twitter bootstrap, (Google Bootstrap - Popup). Each method is smarter than the other depending on the requirements and what you need it to achieve.

Comment: The answers Ive found has been javascript, but I cant get that to work inside PHP :/ As i mentioned this is only my 3rd day using PHP :)

Comment: >>Create a form in another php with ok and cancel
>>Using javascript open the php file in iframe in same document 
>>Use a function to cover this entire process so that the function will return true or false

Comment: PHP cannot do "popups", because it's purely server-side. If you want an actual popup, you need to employ client-side Javascript. This is a bit broad to answer in detail, since you're apparently lacking quite a bit of basics for something like this.

Comment: My development experience is mainly java and .net - Ive just started my internship so Im learning php now. Im aware PHP cant do it, no reason to be rude..

Comment: It was a statement of facts, not intended to be rude. It's fine to not know something, but if the gap between here and there is too wide to realistically talk you through it within the scope of a few paragraphs, you need to put in some more time yourself closing that gap a bit before we can really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript confirm box on onclick attribute for submit button. It will give you yes and cancel options.

```
<input type="submit" value="Bestil" onclick="confirm("Are you sure ?");">
```

Orelse
You can write a function in javascript to check that

```
<input type="submit" value="Bestil" onclick="myfunct();">


function myfunct(){
if(document.getElementById("antal").value > 1)
confirm("Are you sure");
return true;
}
```

Comment: When doing that the script doesn't prompt me for anything when using numbers above 1.

Comment: It had to be:
action="submitOrder.php" onSubmit="return aF();"
But then with minor tweaks, it worked!